# Add Calculated Row into a Select

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a single table housing sets of data which I partition to do a Zscore per set.  I calculate the average of the set.  I calculate the STDEV of the set.  I calculate the ZScore of the set.

Then per set I want to add to the SELECT partitions a row that has 'My Label', [Set columns], [Calculated Partition Average+X*STDEV)

Below uses X=1.5 and the table data would contain partitioned apple and orange data

```
item    value avg   stdev
apple     1    2    0.81
apple     2    2    0.81
apple     3    2    0.81
my apple  3.2  null null
orange    2    4.6  2.49
orange    4    4.6  2.49
orange    8    4.6  2.49
my orange 8.4   null null
```

Comment: so what would the expected results be?

Comment: That was the expected result, with the added 'my x' rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I assumed you meant STDEVP, not STDEV)
You could do that with a query like this (including sample data creation - table @t):

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(item VARCHAR(10), value FLOAT);
INSERT INTO @t(item, value)
VALUES('apple', 1),
    ('apple', 2),
    ('apple', 3),
    ('orange', 2),
    ('orange', 4),
    ('orange', 8);


DECLARE @factor FLOAT=1.5;


WITH
    tmp AS (
               SELECT item, value, AVG(value) OVER (PARTITION BY item) AS [Avg], STDEVP(value) OVER (PARTITION BY item) AS [StdevP]
               FROM @t
               UNION ALL
               SELECT item, AVG(value)+(STDEVP(value)* @factor) AS [Value], NULL AS [avg], NULL AS [StdevP]
               FROM @t
               GROUP BY item
           )
SELECT CASE WHEN [Avg] IS NULL THEN 'My ' ELSE '' END+item AS [Label], value, [Avg], [StdevP]
FROM tmp
ORDER BY item, CASE WHEN [Avg] IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
```